# Background clicks with Bluetooth headphones

Tags: bluetooth, headphones

After a long and frustrating struggle, I finally got my Bluetooth headset to work in Kubuntu 18.04. (The key step was disabling the normal output to the laptop speakers.) The only problem is annoying background clicks every few seconds.  Is that fixable?  If so,how?

Comment: Do you have the same clicks with normal speakers or headphones? For example, my normal speakers appear to pickup internal desktop hard drive clicking. If not could you be more descriptive about the noise you are hearing?

Comment: The clicks seem to have gone away.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was too impatient.  The clicks have gone away.  On the other hand, I've seen other folks report extraneous sounds, which is what led me to report the clicks.